# How do I pass data from a field in angular formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

so I have these fields

```
vm.prepFields = [

{
    key: 'shirt',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Choose Shirt Size',
        placeholder: 'Select option',
        options: shirt_list
    }
},

{
              key: 'shortsq',
              type: 'checkbox',

              templateOptions: {
              label: 'Shorts',

              }
              },


              {
              key: 'shorts',
              type: 'select',
              templateOptions: {
              label: 'Choose Shorts Size',
              options: shorts_list
              }, expressionProperties: {
                hide: '!model.shortsq'
              } 
              }
];
```

}

shortsq is a checkbox, which when clicked shows the shorts select option....how can I pass a value if shorts is checked?

e.g. Lets say the price of a shirt is $10, I want that price to increase by $5 when shorts is checked. how can I accomplish this?

Comment: could you setup a plunkr?I believe this is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by using onChange in the templateOptions:

```
            {
              key: 'shortsq',
              type: 'checkbox',

              templateOptions: {
                  label: 'Shorts',
                  onChange: function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
                      if($scope.model.shortsq) $scope.model.shirtPrice += 5; //increase price by $5 when checked
                      else $scope.model.shirtPrice -= 5; //reduce price by $5 when not checked
                  }
              }
            },
```